# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET returned by registerRoute's handler

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, service-worker, workbox

I have very simple `workbox 3.2` config as follow:

```
const pagesHandler = workbox.strategies.networkOnly();
workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('/?(?:id|en|sg|my|bn)/?$'), pagesHandler);
```

The route is picked up correctly by Workbox:

[image]

But the response is always 200 with warning
[image]

Inspecting the network tab reveals that Service Worker failed returning the document:

[image]

There is `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` tooltip on the "failed" text above.

There is no error in `/en` route (it runs in production for months) and no problems happen if that route is not registered to service worker (by removing the snippet above). I also try changing the caching strategies to `networkFirst`.

In the same `sw.js`, I also have precache route (`workbox.precaching`) and they **all work ok** (can be cached and served by SW)

[image]

What might be wrong with this? And how to resolve?
`/en` is React page with server rendering, served by NodeJS.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this—I put together https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeffposnick/25e084273dbaef941d39b08870f16f8b/raw/d8a0d52bf6440f1e8ba17058a039a43a32298044/index.html which is roughly the same thing, but I'm not seeing the error that you describe. Could you pass along a URL that reproduces the issue? Can you also try checking the "Preserve log" box in the Network panel in Chrome DevTools? And do you see this issue in browsers other than Chrome?

Comment: @JeffPosnick The production URL is https://www.hijup.com/en, can you cache that? (the service worker is currently turned off in that production server). It doesn't happen in Firefox 61.0b2 Developer Edition. The error happens on Chrome 66.0.3359.139, Mac

Comment: Following the error log further, I arrived at: Network request for '/en/' threw an error. TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope': 'only-if-cached' can be set only with 'same-origin' mode

Comment: There's background on the `only-if-cached` behavior at https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/159. With your config, Workbox uses whatever event.request that is created by the browser, so I guess the question is why Chrome is setting `event.request.cache` to `only-if-cached` when `event.request.mode` is presumably set to `navigate`. Do you have a staging server where you can enable a SW so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: It's weird that today I can't simulate this while previously I can always simulate. It's in production now: https://hijup.com/en if you wanna check. The `only-if-cached` issue still happens, but it doesn't trigger the problem described in this Question (which results in blank page)

Comment: I'm using Chrome 66.0.3359.181 and https://www.hijup.com/en loads as expected for me. I can see that you have a strategy of `networkFirst` rather than `networkOnly` in your current https://www.hijup.com/serviceworker.js file, though.